# How can I use a type synonym in an instance declaration?

Tags: haskell

I'd like to make synonyms for a class constraint like the following (very much simplified) example

```
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}

type Foo = Functor

data MyFunctor a = MyFunctor

instance Foo MyFunctor where
  fmap _ _ = MyFunctor
```

but I get `fmap is not a (visible) method of class Foo`.

It seems like I *should* be able to do this because [the GHC documentation](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4.1/html/users_guide/constraint-kind.html) says "... standard constraints, tuples and type synonyms for those two sorts of constraint are permitted in instance contexts and superclasses".  I'm on GHC 7.6.

Comment: I came across this problem and found this question, only to discover the original question was written by me four years ago.  I can confirm this behaviour is still annoying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your case isn't covered by those statements in the GHC documentation. An instance context using `Foo` is something like:

```
 instance Foo a => Bar a
```

A superclass would be something like:

```
 class Foo a => Bar a
```

i.e. you're defining some other class or instance and `Foo`/`Functor` is one of the requirements. Here you're actually trying to define `Functor` itself and you have to use the real class name.

Comment: I see.  What can go wrong with using type synonyms instead of the real class name?  Would it lead to looping like the example in the GHC doc?  (I have to say I don't understand that anyway...)

Comment: At a guess, just user confusion and making the language more complex. Also what would declaring an instance for type Foo a = (Eq a, Ord a) do, for example? It's certainly possible to imagine how it could work, but it's not totally trivial.

Comment: Well I imagine the type synonym would have to resolve to something you can give an instance for.  Anyway, I wanted to use it to reduce boilerplate because I have a MPTC like `ClassName profunctorType a b` and I want my users to provide instances like `ClassName MyProfunctor (MyWrapper TheirType) TheirType` and I'd *really* like to do `type Foo theirType = ClassName MyProfunctor (MyWrapper theirType) TheirType` so they can give instances for `Foo TheirType` instead.